How to turn oven back on after Blackout on Yom Tov
If a blackout occurred during Yom Tov and after the electricity went back on, the oven didn't turn on again, is it permissible to ask a non-Jew to turn it on?
What about having the non-Jew set it to Shabbat Mode? The latter is important given that in new ovens the light will come on and the heat will turn off when the oven door is opened without Shabbat Mode.
Would it make a difference if it is a gas or a electric oven?

How is a blackout relevant to the analysis? In other words, why is the question different than simply asking "may one ask a gentile to turn their oven on during Y"T?"

Specifying the type of oven (gas or electric) could also be important to the analysis.

@Deuteronomy not sure if and how it impacts the answer, hence the question

It could be relevant @Deuteronomy. The reason for the issur of Amira l'akum is fear that we will rely on it. This is a circumstance that is "one off", so some poskim might be lenient. See this answer for this principle actually being used in a different circumstance: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/134732/31534

@RabbiKaii good point :)
